# Using gitpython, how can I checkout a certain Git commit ID?

Tags: python-3.x, gitpython

Checking out a branch works well, but I also need to check out a certain commit ID in a given Git repository.

I mean the equivalent of

```
git clone --no-checkout my-repo-url my-target-path
cd my-target-path
git checkout my-commit-id
```

How can I do this with gitpython?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```py
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(repo_url, repo_path, no_checkout=True)
repo.git.checkout(commit_id)
```

You can find more details in the [documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I looked at the documentation, but it was not clear to me.